# How to executes a .bat file on local machine from adobe animate application?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, adobe-animate

I build a button on adobe animate project and I want to import a (.bat) file but it's open with browser. how does it open with Cmd ????

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var batURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("71.bat")

function btnDown(event:MouseEvent):void{

    navigateToURL(batURL,"_self");
}


button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btnDown)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the local computer, you'll have to compile your application using the [Adobe AIR SDK](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html).

Using Air, you can start a [native process](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) to execute your bat file on Windows.

```
var file:File = new File("C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"); 
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
processArgs.push("/c C:\path\to\bat\71.bat");

var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file; 
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess(); 
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```